# How can I plot a grouped histogram with LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I would like to produce a *grouped* categorical histogram with **LibreOffice Calc**.
With *grouped* I mean an histogram with N columns instead of a single one for each category.

Something like this:

[image: grouping.gif]

Any clue?

Comment: @tohuwawohu: you were right!

Comment: i've transformed my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get such a diagram almost automatically with a 3x3 input matrix:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I am trying to provide an answer for new users who want to generate basic Histogram in Libreoffice Calc.

The first step is to make the frequency array.

- https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html#bm_id3153883

The second step is to generate a Bar Graph based on the frequency array.

[image]

Comment: [ScottAndrewRogers's answer to *Excel histogram*](https://superuser.com/questions/553121/excel-histogram/699255#699255) also works for OpenOffice and LibreOffice.

Comment: the help link to frequency doesn't work anymore :(

Comment: @patapouf_ai Try this, https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060107.html#bm_id3153883 , will update the Answer.